# How to force a resource pack on a world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I have a world I want to distribute to the public but I need to give it a resource pack so I can retexture stuff without downloading it. **Simplified: How can I force a resource pack so they don't have to download it?**

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is name your resource pack `resources.zip` and place it in your world file. When the world loads up, the pack will be loaded automatically.

Comment: I've tried doing that but then it said" "Resource Pack couldn't be applied. Proceed?"

Comment: @TheyCallMeFatibrd Please check the validity of the pack. Make sure all the MCMETA options are correct and that everything has the correct name and folder.

Comment: Here is the branch: worldfile - `resources.zip` - `resources` - `assets`, `pack.mcmeta`, pack.png
In `pack.mcmeta`, I have; {
  `"pack": {
    "pack_format": 15,
    "description": "Minecraft's Default Textures for Community Creators!"
  }
}`

Comment: Im no expert at code but it could be with the format?

Comment: @TheyCallMeFatibrd Why is there a `resources` folder? On the top level of the zip file should be `assets`, `pack.mcmeta`, and `pack.png`.

Comment: I have already tried that so I thought this could work but no, same error message

Comment: @TheyCallMeFatibrd Please look at a tutorial for making resourcepacks online. Test it out by applying it manually. Once you've verified it works, rename it to `resources.zip` and place it in the world folder.